# Howto specify DateTime kind with Settings class?

Tags: c#, datetime, application-settings

By default Settings class does not store information of the DateTime kind to the configuration file, how do I have the DateTime serialized so that it will be saved and retrieved with kind intact?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help.   I used the [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/datesinjson.htm) library to do my serialization and a memory stream.  One of the first things you need to do is make sure that your DateTime object has the Kind you expect it to have.  I used [LINQPad.NET](https://www.linqpad.net/) to create this little demonstration.  I have made use of the legendary Dump method

```
.Dump()
```

This method will take the .NET DateTime object and spit out the values to the results window.  As you can see I've targeted the Kind property that you were asking about.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var date = new DateTime(2015, 12, 25, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
    date.Kind.Dump();

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Serialize(date, memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        var deserializedDate = Deserialize<DateTime>(memoryStream);
        deserializedDate.Kind.Dump();
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static void Serialize( object value, Stream s ) 
{
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(s);

    JsonTextWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer);
    JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
    ser.Serialize(jsonWriter, value);
    writer.Flush();     
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(Stream s) 
{
    T result;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s))
    {
        JsonTextReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader);
        JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
        result = ser.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
    }   
    return result;
}
```

Play with this demo code and change the local kind from DateTimeKind.Local to DateTimeKind.Utc and verify that this works for you.  If you have any questions I'll be glad to try to help.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a simpler solution than dacke.geo's anwers so I'm answering my own question with a solution which I settled with. Though this does not answer my original question exhaustively, using an accessor and assuming Utc time gets the job done in my case:

```
internal static DateTime MyDate
{
    get { return DateTime.SpecifyKind(Properties.Settings.Default.MyDate, DateTimeKind.Utc); }
    set { Properties.Settings.Default.MyDate = value.ToUniversalTime(); }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I included too much information, I was under the assumption that you needed to serialize the information so I provided an example using Json.  I'm glad you found a solution that works for you.